# "Tag" ... Special functionality in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

MSDN says "Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this element." which means I can store anything I want in this property.

But if you bind to this property (with property of type String having a value say "XYZ") and use it in Trigger conditions it doesn't work!

```
  <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="XYZ">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
  </Trigger>
```

It does not set the background red. You can try and assume myElement to be a TextBlock! Why is it like this?

Comment: Sorry just edited. Did it work with Binding?

Comment: yes, i'll post all the code as an answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tag has no special functionality in WPF.

This works for me:

```
<TextBlock Tag="{Binding Data}"
           x:Name="tb">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="TextBlock.Tag"
                         Value="XYZ">
                     <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background"
                             Value="Lime" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>        
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

And setting the Data object property to "XYZ" in an event.

Comment: Strange! The trigger seems to be not occurring at my end!!

Comment: Sorry Erno my bad! Setting the value works (which I thought wasn't working)... but with Binding to Tag property, is it working? My source property bound to Tag is a String... I have edited my post.

Comment: @AngelWPF, Is your class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and triggering it?

Comment: Yes it does. :(... its actually a simple TextBlock, having a simple class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and its instance as a data context of the TextBlock. In fact the default value of the property is "XYZ", so I expect Red background to appear on load itself.

Comment: @AngelWPF, show us the code, that's the only way we can comment. When I set the property to "XYZ" by default the trigger still works.

Comment: @AngelWPF, Your code works for me. Do you see any binding errors in the output?

Comment: Yes as a matter of fact I do! I am a moron. Please downvote me!

Comment: @AngelWPF, it's ok to make mistakes, in fact it is the only way we learn, so make many more. What was your error?

Answer (score 13):

The `Tag` is a construct held over from Winforms days (and possibly there from before that!).  It was used as a convenient place to associate an object with a UI element, such as a FileInfo with a Button, so in the Button's event handler you could simply take the event sender, cast it to a Button, then cast the `Tag` value to a FileInfo and you have everything you need about the file you want to open.

*There is one situation*, however, where I've found the `Tag` is useful in WPF.  I've used it as a holding spot that can be accessed by a ContextMenu MenuItem, which can't use the normal RelativeSource bindings you'd use to traverse the visual tree.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter
                Property="Tag"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=TheUserControlRootElement}" />
            <Setter
                Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem
                            Header="_Remove"
                            ToolTip="Remove this from this list"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                            Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.Remove, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

From the `ContextMenu`, I cannot access the **Remove** command which is defined in the `UserControl` class where this snippet is defined.  But I can bind the root to the `Tag` of the `ListBoxItem`, which I *can access* via the `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` property.  The same trick can be used when binding within a `ToolTip`, as the same limitations apply.

Comment: Cheers for that spicy situation.

Answer (score 2):

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="wpftest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="test" MouseDown="test_MouseDown"
                   Tag="{Binding TestProperty}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="XYZ">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new TestViewModel();
    }

    private void test_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TestViewModel)DataContext).TestProperty = "XYZ";
    }

    private sealed class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _testPropertyValue;

        public string TestProperty
        {
            get { return _testPropertyValue; }
            set
            {
                _testPropertyValue = value;
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                if(handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestProperty"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Updated: `Tag` property now is bound to `TestProperty`.